# yii selenium radio button is checked?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, yii

I am trying to tell which of two radio buttons is checked. I have no problem testing the values of text inputs and dropdowns, but I just can't seem to figure out how to test whether or not a radio button is checked.

I am using the selenium test driver with yii (not yii2) in php. Does anybody know how to do this?

For example, how would I determine which of the following radio buttons is checked?

```
<input id="gender_0" value="M" type="radio" name="gender">
<input id="gender_1" value="F" type="radio" name="gender">
```

The way that I am trying to do it now is like this

```
$this->assertNotNull('#gender_'.($gender == 'M' ? 0 : 1).':checked');
$this->assertNull('#gender_'.($gender == 'M' ? 1 : 0).':checked');
```

The following works in a web browser's console, but I don't know how to do it in php with yii's Selenium web driver.

```
console.assert(document.querySelector('#gender_0:checked') != null);
```

Comment: where is your code how are you trying to check it currently

Comment: I have updated my original post with an example

Comment: you are using codeception or not

Comment: I am not using codeception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem for me:

```
$this->assertChecked('id=gender_'.($gender == 'M' ? 0 : 1));
$this->assertNotChecked('id=gender_'.($gender == 'M' ? 1 : 0));
```

I used assertChecked and assertNotChecked instead of assertNotNull and assertNull, changed the '#' to 'id=', and removed ':checked'.